# how to reduce time complexity of clustering over doc2vec embedding?

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding, doc2vec, annoy

I have a bunch of vectors of 300 dimensions each, as part of doc2vec embedding. Each vector is a representation of an article. My goal is to discard the duplicate articles. I was thinking of running [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.dbscan.html) clustering over my dataset, and then for each cluster label, discard the duplicates. I chose DBSCAN because it's hierarchical, and it can take cosine distance as metric, which I think makes more sense than euclidean distance for document similarity detection.

Issue is, if I choose cosine distance, then sklearn DBSCAN implementation doesn't allow ‘ball_tree’ and ‘kd_tree’ as the algorithm, hence I'm left with ‘brute’, which I'm guessing has O(n^2) complexity when run for all vectors.

If I don't go the clustering route, then I see two options. Calculate similarity using the `most_similar` method for all vectors, either in vanilla doc2vec, or through annoy index. According to [this](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_annoy.html) doc vanilla doc2vec has linear complexity for similarity query, whereas annoy gives sub-linear time complexity. I'd like to know, which one would be the best choice given my use case? Is there a better approach I'm missing?

Comment: The best way to find for sure which approach is best for your use case, or even practical given your data/resources/goals, is to try a bunch of alternatives & see which works best. Note that if vectors are scaled to all be of unit-length, euclidean distance & cosine-distance will always report the same rank-ordered nearest-neighbors, so the choice may not as stark as your suggest. When compared on some representative test set, which does better?

Comment: @gojomo I went ahead with annoy indexes in the end. Seemed to serve my purpose well.